# Can I select specific rows to colour in a ggplot bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two columns of data to plot in a bar chart, there are 378 observations. I would like to select particular rows and make them a different colour to the other rows. For example, rows 1-359 blue, but rows 360-378 to be black. My current code is;

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(ID, Total),
             y = Total))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", colour = "steelblue3")
```

I've tried playing around with scale_fill_manual but it doesn't seem to be working! Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: can you add an example of reproducible code? with an input data frame, on Iris data for example

Comment: Add a column to your data that's an indicator for color, then map that to the fill aesthetic. (`color` only colors the outlines of bars, `fill` colors the whole bar).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).